# Character Break in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This is the original code and I think there might be a problem if I put spaces in the string it would print another line, but the goal is that helloworld cannot be touched and still get spaces in between

```
%macro  nwln  0
        call    proc_nwln
%endmacro

SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov ecx,msg3
    mov edx,0       ; Set the length
    jmp lab2

lab2:
    cmp [ecx],byte ' '
    je lab1
    cmp [ecx], byte 0
    je lab3
    inc edx
    inc ecx
    jmp lab2
lab1:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln
    add ecx, edx
    inc ecx
    mov edx,0
    jmp lab2

lab3:
    sub ecx,edx
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    int 80h
    nwln

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    int 80h

proc_nwln:
    pusha
    mov    eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov    ebx, STDOUT
    mov    ecx, new_line
    mov    edx, 0x1
    int    0x80
    popa
    ret

segment .data
     msg3 db 'HelloWorld', 0xa
     new_line db 0x0a
```

Can you guys help me I'm stuck with this problem how would i break each character in the string without touching it? I know it's easy but I'm stuck any idea?
– string: helloworld
– output:
h
e
l
l
o
w
o
r
l
d

Comment: Print a character, print a space, increment pointer, loop.  Or make a copy on the stack with the spaces in between.  Can you think about how you would write it in a somewhat higher-level language like C?

Comment: This program appears to be a somewhat convoluted way to print space-separated words on separate lines, i.e. printing a newline instead of a space.  Why did you write this, and why is it in your question about a different problem?  (Or if you didn't write it, better link where you got it from, with attribution.  Plagiarism is bad.)